# VirtualBox мост в hostednetwork

Tags: windows, администрирование, wifi, virtualbox, bridge

Есть:

- Гость Debian 9
- Хост Windows 10 LTSB VBox 5.2.16r

На хосте запущена сеть виртуальной точки доступа (hostednetwork) и отключена служба ICS.
Гость мостом пробрасывается в эту сеть, чтобы выступать в роли шлюза, dhcp, dns.

Смартфон при подключении к сети без проблем получает ip-адрес и общается с гостевой ОС, т.е. проходят все пинги, работают все dns запросы, все работает если на прямую обращаться к шлюзу или его сервисам.

Проблема заключается в раздаче интернета (NAT), до шлюза (гостевой ОС) не доходят forward пакеты от смартфона. Проверял с помощью wireshark и tcpdump.

Как ни странно данная связка без проблем работала на windows 10 single language.
Предполагаю какой-то процесс или сама windows ловит все forward пакеты еще до гостевой машины, уже неделю не могу определить что мешает.

В чем может быть проблема?
[image: HostedNetwork]
[image: VBox Bridge]